# last activity time from the facebook app?

Tags: ios, facebook, time, android-activity

My iOS app has facebook integration and it displays a set of users (facebook friends) who has the app installed. The list has to be sorted based on the last activity time of the users.

Is it possible to get the last activity time from facebook? If then any ideas about how to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the last time a user was active on Facebook. You would probably have to manage (on your server) the last time a user accessed your app and use that to order the list.